I need help sprite animation with CSS and JS
I made this simple project that allows a 4-image sprite to move in one direction, but I would like to know how I can do this so that whenever the D key (key that moves the character) is not being pressed, the AnimationIndex is the same to 0, giving the impression that the character has stopped.
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var V = 40;
            var boneco = $('.boneco');
            var animacoes = ['direita', 'direita2', 'direita3', 'direita4']; // 4 pois o sprite de andar para a direita contém apenas 4 imagens
            var animacaoIndex = 1;
            var teclaDisponivel = true;

            function moverBonecoDireita() {
                var andou = parseInt(boneco.css('margin-left')) || 0; // lembrar: tudo que vem do css vem como string, usar parseInt para converter
                var larguraTela = $(window).width(); // tam tela
                var larguraBoneco = boneco.width(); // tam boneco

                if (andou + V + larguraBoneco <= larguraTela) {
                    boneco.removeClass(animacoes[animacaoIndex]);
                    animacaoIndex = (animacaoIndex + 1) % animacoes.length;
                    boneco.addClass(animacoes[animacaoIndex]);
                    boneco.css('margin-left', (andou + V) + 'px');
                }
            }

            $(document).on('keypress', function (evento) {
                var tecla = evento.keyCode;
                if (tecla == 100 && teclaDisponivel) { // tecla 'd'
                    teclaDisponivel = false;
                    moverBonecoDireita();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        teclaDisponivel = true;
                    }, 110);
                } else if (tecla == 97) { // tecla 'a'
                    boneco.removeClass(animacoes.join(' '));
                    boneco.css('margin-left', '0px');
                    animacaoIndex = 1;
                }
            });
        });


I tried to create a command block so that, when pressing the D key, animationindex would be equal to 0, but I failed

$(document).ready(function () {
    var V = 40;
    var boneco = $('.boneco');
    var animacoes = ['direita', 'direita2', 'direita3', 'direita4']; 
    var animacaoIndex = 0; 
    var teclaDisponivel = true;

    function moverBonecoDireita() {
        var andou = parseInt(boneco.css('margin-left')) || 0; 
        var larguraTela = $(window).width(); 
        var larguraBoneco = boneco.width(); 

        if (andou + V + larguraBoneco <= larguraTela) {
            boneco.removeClass(animacoes[animacaoIndex]);
            animacaoIndex = (animacaoIndex + 1) % animacoes.length;
            boneco.addClass(animacoes[animacaoIndex]);
            boneco.css('margin-left', (andou + V) + 'px');
        }
    }

    $(document).on('keypress', function (evento) {
        var tecla = evento.keyCode;
        if (tecla == 100 && teclaDisponivel) { // 'D' key
            teclaDisponivel = false;
            moverBonecoDireita();
            setTimeout(function () {
                teclaDisponivel = true;
            }, 110);
        } else if (tecla == 97) {
            boneco.removeClass(animacoes.join(' '));
            boneco.css('margin-left', '0px');
            animacaoIndex = 0;
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', function (evento) {
        var tecla = evento.keyCode;
        if (tecla == 100) { 
            boneco.removeClass(animacoes.join(' '));
            animacaoIndex = 0;
            boneco.addClass(animacoes[animacaoIndex]);
        }
    });
});

animacaoIndex = 0; Initialization: The animacaoIndex starts at 0 to represent the first frame of the animation.
This should give you the desired effect where the sprite animation resets to the first frame when the "D" key is not pressed.
